# Raster image shown displaced?

Tags: raster, arcmap, geotiff-tiff

I have a raster-catalog consisting of 332 raster-datasets in tiff-format. Two of the raster-images are shown slightly displaced in north direction, as you can see in picture 2. When zooming out all images seem to line up perfectly (picture 1). Every raster image comes with a header and a world file.

Does anyone know where the gap in presentation could come from?

[image: raster-datasets when zoomed out]

[image: Displaced Image]

Comment: Might be a corrupted pyramid for the individual tiffs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemed to be a corrupt tiff image. I opened image in IrfanView and saved it again by compressing. After adding it to raster catalog again the image was shown correctly.